# Change formula from EV to Shutter Speed equivalent

Tags: logarithms, arithmetic

I have this formula:

$$\mathrm{EV}=\log_2\frac{N^2}t,$$

How can I extract $t$?

$t = ?$

Answer (score 1):

*Hint*:

If $a=b$, then $2^a=2^b$.

Another hint:

What is $2^{\log_2 x}$ equal to?

Comment: Square root of 2 applied to both sides?

Comment: @IdanShechter Did you even read my answer? Again, I ask you. What is $2^{\log_2 x}$?

Comment: 2 power of EV, right?

Comment: @IdanShechter I am trying to guide you to the correct answer. For that, first answer this simple question: What is $2^{\log_2x}$ equal to?

Comment: it is equals to: log2x * log2x

Comment: @IdanShechter Does it now? So if I take $x=2$, then $\log_2 x = 1$, so $2^{\log_2 x} = 2$. However, $\log_2x\cdot \log_2x =1\cdot 1 = 1$. So no, $2^{\log_2 x}$ does not equal to $\log_2x\cdot \log_2x$. I suggest you have a look at some introductory text about logarithms and power functions. You could start http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm here.